# how to properly use arrays, as opposed to using dynamic scalar variables

Tags: perl

I have this kind of data and need to (1) retrieve the first element (5 elements in each "number cluster", separated by ":") within each cluster and (2) group the retrieved elements every 3 elements per group.

```
chr1    69270   .   A   G   1/1:208,34:244:14.96:118,15,0   0/1:186,51:241:8.72:80,0,9  0/0:226,1:236:3.01:0,3,30   ./. 1/1:209,35:250:12:116,12,0  ./. 1/1:186,53:242:14.97:126,15,0   0/0:245,0:248:3.01:0,3,33   1/1:182,60:243:23.95:201,24,0
```

I am sure there are better way to do it. But as of now, I could only think of using brutal force, which is always bad. The other option is to use dynamic scalars but essentially dynamic scalars would do exactly what the bad code below does. I don't see much improvement and others at stackoverflow said it's (also) always bad to use dynamic scalars.

I am still reading perl beginning so don't know what other options are available. Any help will be appreciated.

```
my @genotype1 = split (/:/, $original_line[6]);
my @genotype2 = split (/:/, $original_line[7]);
my @genotype3 = split (/:/, $original_line[8]);
my @genotype4 = split (/:/, $original_line[9]);
my @genotype5 = split (/:/, $original_line[10]);
my @genotype6 = split (/:/, $original_line[11]);
my @genotype7 = split (/:/, $original_line[12]);
my @genotype8 = split (/:/, $original_line[13]);
my @genotype9 = split (/:/, $original_line[14]);
my @trio1 = ($genotype1[0], $genotype2[0], $genotype3[0]);
my @trio2 = ($genotype4[0], $genotype5[0], $genotype6[0]);
my @trio3 = ($genotype7[0], $genotype8[0], $genotype9[0]);
```

Comment: What the heck is a dynamic scalar? Searching for "dynamic scalar" on stackoverflow yields two other questions, neither of them related to Perl.

Comment: @mob: I *think* he might mean symbolic references, but that's pretty much just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using "dynamic variables", you would have

```
for (6..14) {
   @{ "genotype".($i-6) } = split (/:/, $original_line[$i]);
}
```

Just change it to

```
my @genotypes;
for (6..14) {
   @{ $genotypes[$i-6] } = split (/:/, $original_line[$i]);
}
```

which might be a bit cleaner as

```
my @genotypes;
for (6..14) {
   $genotypes[$i-6] = [ split (/:/, $original_line[$i]) ];
}
```

or

```
my @genotypes;
for (6..14) {
   push @genotypes, [ split (/:/, $original_line[$i]) ];
}
```

or

```
my @genotypes;
for (@original_line[6..14]) {
   push @genotypes, [ split /:/ ];
}
```

or

```
my @genotypes = map { [ split /:/ ] } @original_line[6..14];
```

But you only need the first element, so you can use

```
my @genotypes = map { ( split /:/ )[0] } @original_line[6..14];
```

Then, all you need is to grab three elements from that array at a time, so you get:

```
my @genotypes = map { ( split /:/ )[0] } @original_line[6..14];

my @trioes;
while (@genotypes) {
   push @trios, [ splice @genotypes, 0, 3 ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several different ways to make your code more efficient; most (all?) would take advantage of the fact that you're only ever using the first element of each `@genotype` list.  One example:

```
my @elements = map { (split /:/)[0] } @original_line[6..14];
my @trio1 = @elements[0,1,2];
my @trio2 = @elements[3,4,5];
my @trio3 = @elements[6,7,8];
```